# ModelState is invalid when trying to insert into table with foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm stuck on problem when trying to insert into table `Novel` with scaffolded codes generated using entity framework. No error shows, debugger tells me that the foreign keys are `ValidationState=Invalid`.

Here is my Novel table:

[image: The column NovelID is indentify]

Here is the `Novel.cs` model generated using scafolding:

```
public partial class Novel
{
    [Key]
    public int NovelId { get; set; }

    public string NovelTitle { get; set; } = null!;

    public string NovelDescription { get; set; } = null!;

    public string NovelCover { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime NovelDatePost { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public int NovelView { get; set; } = 1; 

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; } = new List<Chapter>();

    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComments { get; } = new List<UserComment>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserRating> UserRatings { get; } = new List<UserRating>();

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; } = new List<Genre>();
}
```

`Author.cs`

```
public partial class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Novel> Novels { get; } = new List<Novel>();
}
```

`User.cs`

```
public partial class User
{
    [DisplayName("Login ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; } = null!;

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; } = null!;

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Novel> Novels { get; } = new List<Novel>();

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComments { get; } = new List<UserComment>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserRating> UserRatings { get; } = new List<UserRating>();
}
```

I created a View Model for this, `NovelViewModel.cs` :

```
public class NovelViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelCover { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action `NovelsController.cs`:

```
// GET: Novels/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        NovelViewModel novel = new NovelViewModel();
        ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorId");
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserId");
        return View(novel);
    }

// POST: Novels/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(NovelViewModel novel)
{
    try
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(novel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
    }
    ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorName", novel.AuthorID);
    ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserId", novel.UserID);
    return View(novel);
}
```

View `Create.cshtml`

```
@model WebNovel.Models.ViewModels.NovelViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Novel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelCover" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelCover" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelCover" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AuthorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="AuthorID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AuthorId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="UserID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Debugger shows the 2 foreign keys value are `ValidationState=Invalid` when I put breakpoint at `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

[image: ValidationState=Invalid]

I really don't understand where I do it wrong here. It will be appreciated if you point where is the error in my code. Sorry if I phrased my problem incorrect.

Comment: Is it actually has foreign key to `Author`  table by `AuthorId` in database?

Comment: @hamaronooo Yes, it is in database. I created database first then I use scaffolding to create models. https://imgur.com/a/wIRWiiv

Comment: Please provide full text of exception

Comment: I don't know what you mean, sorry. My english isn't good, can you point out where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC view will not send you back full `Author` or `User` objects.
But actually, you are don't need them in your `POST` controller action.
For `Entity framework` enough id of foreign entities for coupling.
If you still need them for some reason, you can query from Database by `id`.

So, create new model for `POST` action.
Like this:

```
public class CreateNovelModel
{
    [Required]
    public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelCover { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in `POST` action:

```
// POST: Novels/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNovelModel novel)
///...
```

Comment: Oh, I understand the problem now. Thanks. But I run into error `InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'NovelViewModel' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.` When the code reach line `_context.Add(novel);`. So can I ask how to fix that.

Comment: Your `NovelViewModel` is NOT an entity type! You can't add it to DbContext.

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out. The `NovelViewModel` have to convert to `Novel` before adding it to database. Thanks for all the helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting any author and user info (and you should not, for multiple reasons, like preventing [over posting attacks](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/aspnet-overpostingmass-assignment-model-binding-security)), so remove `User` and `Author` properties from the view model:

```cs
public class NovelViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String NovelCover { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
}
```

P.S.

`RequiredAttribute` potentially will not work as expected on the `AuthorID` - [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751005/2501279) for example.

Comment: But, maybe, `Author` and `User` objects needed in View for some data displaying

Comment: @hamaronooo - I highly doubt that - based on select lists used.

Comment: Thanks for the help too. Both is answer I need but I can only mark 1.